# How to perform action after any change happens to the table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to audit the table data change into the audit_log table.
Let's say I have two tables: audit_log and test_table. Whenever a new entry goes to the test_table, the audit_log table should note newly added data. Same for update and delete actions. I tried with triggers which work great but for this, I have to write three triggers for a single table.

**Trigger for update:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trig_test_table_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `test_table` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE var_reason varchar(250);
    DECLARE var_updated_by varchar(100);
    DECLARE var_table_name varchar(150);
    DECLARE var_record_id int(11);
    DECLARE var_updated_by_role int(11);
    DECLARE var_updated_on datetime;

    SET var_reason = NEW.update_reason;
    SET var_updated_by = NEW.updated_by;
    SET var_updated_by_role = NEW.updated_by_role;
    SET var_table_name = 'test_table';
    SET var_record_id = NEW.test_table_id;
    SET var_updated_on = now();

    IF NEW.category <> OLD.category THEN
    INSERT INTO audit_log(table_name,record_id,field_name,old_value,new_value,update_reason,updated_from_screen,updated_by,updated_on,update_by_role)
    VALUES (var_table_name,var_record_id,'category',OLD.category,NEW.category,var_reason,NEW.updated_from_screen,
        var_updated_by,var_updated_on,var_updated_by_role);
    END IF;
END
```

This works fine but I have to create another trigger for insert and delete actions which I don't want. Is there any solution in **MySQL** through which I can handle insert, update and delete actions in a single file? Or is there any trick that we can do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Is there any solution in MySQL through which I can handle insert, update and delete actions in a single file?* Noway.

Comment: @Akina Thanks a lot for your response. Is there any trick you can suggest?

Comment: The only "trick" which I can imagine is stored procedure which saves provided  parameters values into the log database. Triggers simply calls it (UPDATE trigger - twice). Alternatively you may restrict direct data access and use only stored procedures for data change - they allows save debug/archive data in more clear (and maybe more compact) form.

Comment: Okay, I will try accordingly. Thank you so much for your suggestion.